# Convert every occurence of Fahrenheit to Celsius in the clipboard content in bash

Tags: bash, converters, clipboard, temperature

Real sample text:

> Mealworms do reproduce in temperatures ranging from 65-100 F, but
>   temperatures above 86 º F negatively impact growth and development
>   (inhibiting pupation). The duration of the pupal stage will depend on
>   temperature. It is six days at 91.4 º F, seven days at 80.6 ºF, ten
>   days at 75.2º F and thirteen days at 69.8 °F.

After running the script, the clipboard contents should look like:

> Mealworms do reproduce in temperatures ranging from 18.3-37.8°C, but
>   temperatures above 30.0°C negatively impact growth and development
>   (inhibiting pupation). The duration of the pupal stage will depend on
>   temperature. It is six days at 33.0°C, seven days at 27°C, ten days at
>   24°C and thirteen days at 21°C.

Sample text with some possible combinations:

```
100 F
50-100 F
50 - 100 F
50.5 - 100.22 F

100.22F
100.22°F
100.22 °F
100.22 ° F

100.22ºF
100.22 ºF
100.22 º F
```

I'd run the script as a system wide shortcut, so pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I would invoke this script on the contents of the Clipboard and maybe show the converted contents in a popup textbox.

**Update:**
Using @Bertrand Martel 's answer the final script used as a shortcut is:

```
/usr/bin/xclip -selection c -o | /usr/bin/perl -pe's/([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(\s?(°|º)?\s?F)/sprintf("%.1f°C", ($1-32)*1\/1.8)/eg; \
s/([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(-| - )([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)°C/sprintf("%.1f$2$3°C",($1-32)*1\/1.8)/eg' | /usr/bin/xclip -selection c -i && /usr/bin/zenity --info --text="$(/usr/bin/xclip -selection c -o)" --timeout 5
```

When the shortcut is triggered the script converts every occurrence of Fahrenheit to Celsius in the text that was in the clipboard. Then the clipboard is updated with the converted values and the contents are shown in a popup window for 5 seconds.

Comment: This is two completely separate questions slapped into one. The first one, extracting temperatures, is trivial with a `grep -o`. The second, running the script with a system-wide hotkey, is unanswerable, because you didn't even say which OS you're using.

Comment: The second part (running the script with a system-wide hotkey) was not meant to be a question, I just thought it's better to mention the way I'll use the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Perl to extract your floating point number and replace each occurence with the result of conversion :

```
perl -pe's/([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(\s?(°|º)?\s?F)/sprintf("%.1f°C", ($1-32)*1\/1.8)/eg; \
s/([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(-| - )([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)°C/sprintf("%.1f$2$3°C",($1-32)*1\/1.8)/eg' text.txt
```

You can then copy the result to the clipboard using `xclip` on Linux, `clip` on Windows or `pbcopy` on MAC OS :

```
perl -pe's/([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(\s?(°|º)?\s?F)/sprintf("%.1f°C", ($1-32)*1\/1.8)/eg; \
s/([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(-| - )([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)°C/sprintf("%.1f$2$3°C",($1-32)*1\/1.8)/eg' text.txt | xclip
```

Comment: This is crazy.  Perl can perform arithmetic without the help of `bc` (or `cat`, for that matter).

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the answer thank you for your feedback

Comment: So now the remaining problem is that "16 days" will be converted to "-8.888 days" (-:

Comment: That second capture group `( F|F|°F| °F| ° F|ºF| ºF| º F|º F)` would be much simpler as `?([°º] ?)?F` (imagine a leading space there - Markdown is inadequate...).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I changed this capture group to `(\s?(°|º)?\s?F)`